# Are EMI shielded memory modules necessary?

Tags: memory

So, I was asked to upgrade DDR3 ECC RAM on our servers. My current problem is that I am quite unsure on whether buying EMI-shielded memory modules (where a metal plate covers both sides of the module) or not.

The memory modules currently installed have EMI-shielding, but is there a real benefit (apart from the often higher price tag) of it (less read/write errors)?

Comment: What kind of server/motherboard/use-case? They're far from normal

Comment: Just a normal rack configuration (not even a datacenter environment) with a bunch of 2U ProLiant DL180 G6 servers and a TOR-Switch in a little server room (like many small businesses do).

Comment: Is this really EM shielding or just a  heat sink (or better heat spreader)?

Comment: In fact, I am unsure about it. I get your point @Sven, but each vendor (in my case HP) handles it different. Some are advertising heatspreaders as EMI shield and some are just referring to them as heatspreader. But every metal surface on top of a memory chip should provide "some sort of" EMI-shielding.

Comment: They may not even bring something. First, they ARE heat shields. Second, the servers may be older and - there have been advances in DDR ;) Which means newer modules may not need heat spreaders.

Comment: So, to sum it up: heat shielding is not a necessary thing unless you are in a high density config (e.g. having every single bank in your server filled with RAM) and if airflow is decent enough (what servers are designed to guarantee mainly), there won't be any advantage of heat spreaders.

Comment: These "heatspreaders" can help to protect the memory, because you don't touch the memory chips when you hold them in your hands or put them in your pockets. Another benefit is: They look nice and shiny! Apart from that I doubt they are of much use if you're not a hardcore overclocker.

Comment: Working with hardware over years has taught me a few valuable lessons, e.g. NOT to touch anything ESD-sensitive without proper grounding or if you cannot avoid it at least not on the sides where components are placed. I agree with @Freddy, that it might look "shinier".